# How can I get CGPoint?

Tags: swift

I'd like to obtain CGPoint of UIView, but I could not.

What is the correct code?

```
//My Code
let wayPoint = vMapObject.point
print(wayPoint) //(Function)
```

I want the X and Y coordinates as a tuple type.

Comment: What is `vMapObject ` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the view's origin? `vMapObject.frame.origin`.

Comment: You Need frame origin or Touch Location in View ?

Comment: Why do you want a `tuple`? `tuple`s are a uniformly awful way to deal with data. Having a `struct` or object with named members is much better for readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code to get `x` and `y` point for view as tuple.

```
func getPointForView(_ view : UIView) -> (x:CGFloat,y:CGFloat)
{
    let x = view.frame.origin.x
    let y = view.frame.origin.y
    return (x,y)
}
```

From your code I guess, `vMapObject` is your view.
So declared it as `UIView`.

```
var vMapObject : UIView!
```

Make call for that view as below:

```
let point = getPointForView(vMapObject)
print("X : \(point.x)")
print("Y : \(point.y)")
```